# Насколько это будет логично? фильтрация переменных

Tags: php, переменные

Тут мне пришла в голову мысль фильтровать данные через функцию и возвращать отфильтрованные данные "чистая вода". P.S. Возможно я из каменного века и просто не использую Google для поиска и это можно было найти.

```
   function filter ($str) 
    {  
         $str = trim ($str); 
         $str = strip_tags ($str); 
         return $str;

    }

$abc = " <b>Hello World !</b> ";
echo filter ($abc);
```

Это простой пример, но я пошел дальше и все запросы SQL фильтровал через это. Как вы думаете это лучше чем каждый раз писать в каждом файле ?

Comment: >но я пошел дальше и все запросы SQL фильтровал через это.

Предостерегу от велосипедов, используйте правильные  инструменты: [`prepared statements`][1]


  [1]: http://www.php.net/manual/ru/pdo.prepared-statements.php

Comment: Data sanitization должна всегда присутстовать, другой вопрос, что это никоим образом не пересекается с защитой от sql-инъекций.

p.s.

    function filter($string)
    {
        return trim(strip_tags($string));
    }

Comment: @Fike, почему же ?

Comment: @Дмитрий Астафьев, каким образом подобная обработка остановит sql-инъекцию?

    0; UNION SELECT TABLE_SCHEMA, TABLE_NAME, COLUMN_NAME FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS; --

 по-вашему не пройдет?

Comment: @Fike, P.S. "но я пошел дальше и все запросы SQL фильтровал через это"

Comment: @Дмитрий Астафьев, какие виды sql-инъекций отфильтрует эта функция?

Comment: @Fike, если я допишу пару функций для обработки строк то не пройдет. ту же `mysqli_real_escape_string()`

Comment: @Дмитрий Астафьев, если вы прогоните вышеописанную штуку через `mysqli_real_escape_string()`, с ней ничего не случится, и подстановка вместо айдишника все равно выведет злоумышленнику всю инфу по таблицам. Не говоря уж о том, что в этой фильтрации никакого экранирования и не было.

Comment: >если я допишу пару функций

А к ним потом ещё парочку, а к ним - ещё пять, потому что не предусмотрел хитровывернутого... Времени не жалко тратить на то, что уже давно существует "из коробки", отлажено и проверено миллионами пользователей?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Фильтрация переменных [уже реализована](http://www.php.net/manual/ru/book.filter.php) в php. Например:

```
$dirtyHarry = 'Привет <script>alert("hacked");</script> мир!';
echo $filtered = filter_var( $dirtyHarry, FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
// Привет alert(&#34;hacked&#34;); мир!
```